subdivision before displacement creates sharp, noisy geometry

I am trying to apply a heightmap texture to a displacement modifier on a plane which has been loop-cut into an NxN grid.
It results in this spikey geometry. It's as if some vertices in the subdivided polygons are unaffected by the displacement.
Steps to reproduce:

new project
add plane, size=500m
edit mode: loop cut in each direction
object mode: add displace modifier, new texture
texture panel: open image
modifier panel: increase displace strength parameter

This also happens if I use a subdivision surface before the displacement.


hello could you please share your file?

I had to remake it with a lower resolution of subdivision to keep the file small, but the effect is broadly the same.

I don't see the exact same thing in the file you share but anyway it seems to work as it is supposed to, note that the pattern is repeating because you've chosen Coordinates > Local in the modifier, don't you want UV instead?

Your mapping is 'Local' at  size of 500m .. you are seeing, effectively, a Moiré interference pattern with a fine tiling of the original image. Set the mapping in the modifier to 'UV' and adjust strength .. maybe re-unwrap if necessary.

@RobinBetts that fixed it, would you like to post a full answer?

@spraff sure thing.. sorry for late reply.. I'm not able to get to the keyboard as often as I'd like, at the moment.

Your texture-space is set to 'Local'. At a model-size of 500 units, that tiles your image-texture many times across the plane. The result is an interference-pattern between the sampling-points (vertices of your mesh) and the repeating texture.
For the texture to span the square mesh, it should be unwrapped to fill the UV space, and the mapping set to 'UV' in your Displacement modifier.
